# Knockout computed arrays not updating correctly

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am having difficulties getting my view to update according to my viewmodel. To summarize what I'm doing: I have an array of items (AllCredentials). One of the properties for the items is a "IsSelected" value (either true or false). When the value for an item is false (the default value upon creation of the AllCredentials array), the item will appear on the "UnselectedCredentials" list. When an item from this list is double clicked its value for "IsSelected" will get toggled thus making it appear in the other "SelectedCredentials" list.

When I test it out, the "IsSelected" value is getting toggled properly when double clicked but the computed arrays (2 of them, one each corresponding to the 2 lists) aren't getting added/removed to accordingly (as in when an item from the "UnselectedCredentials" list gets double clicked, its value for "IsSelected" should toggle from false to true thus removing it from that list and adding it to the "SelectedCredentials" list).

Here is my code:

VIEWMODEL:

```
var TestNWJS = TestNWJS || {};

TestNWJS.QualificationList = (function () {

//private functions

function FindUnselectedCredentials() { //function to populate UnselectedCredentials list

    var filtering = ko.utils.arrayFilter(TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.AllCredentials(), function (item) {
        return item.IsSelected === false;
    });

    return filtering;
}

function FindSelectedCredentials() { //function to populate SelectedCredentials list

    var filtering = ko.utils.arrayFilter(TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.AllCredentials(), function (item) {
        return item.IsSelected === true;
    });

    return filtering;
}

function CreateQualificationModel(allCredentialsList) {
    TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel = {};

    TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.AllCredentials = ko.observableArray(allCredentialsList);

    TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.UnselectedCredentials = ko.computed(FindUnselectedCredentials, this);
    TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.SelectedCredentials = ko.computed(FindSelectedCredentials, this);

    TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.AllCredentials.extend({ notify: 'always' });
    TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.UnselectedCredentials.extend({ notify: 'always' });
    TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.SelectedCredentials.extend({ notify: 'always' });
}

function toggleselected(id) {
    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.AllCredentials(), function (item) {
        id = parseInt(id);
        return id === item.Id;
    });

    match.IsSelected = !match.IsSelected;
    return match;
}

//public function
return {

    Init: function (allCredentialsList) {
        CreateQualificationModel(allCredentialsList);

        //when you select something from the dropdown this will happen.
        $("select[name='QualificationFilter']").change(function (e) {
            var id = $(this).val();
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(e.target).parents("form");
            var url = window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf("QualificationList") + 17)
            form.attr("action", url + "?Id=" + id);
            form.submit();
        });

        $("#UnselectedCredentialsList").live('dblclick', function (e) {
            toggleselected(this.value);
        });

        $("#SelectedCredentialsList").live('dblclick', function (e) {
            toggleselected(this.value);
        });

        ko.applyBindings(TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel);
    }
}

})();
```

VIEW:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldName_td">
                @Html.Label("Available Credentials")
            </td>
            <td class="fieldData_td">
                <select data-bind="options: UnselectedCredentials,
                                   optionsText: 'Name',
                                   optionsValue: 'Id'"
                                   size="10" multiple="multiple" id="UnselectedCredentialsList"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldName_td">
                @Html.Label("Selected Credentials")
            </td>
            <td class="fieldData_td">
                <select data-bind="options: SelectedCredentials,
                                   optionsText: 'Name',
                                   optionsValue: 'Id'"
                                   size="10" multiple="multiple" id="SelectedCredentialsList"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
}
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js", "~/jscripts/Administration/Interfaces/QualificationList.js", "~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        TestNWJS.QualificationList.Init(@Html.Raw(Model.JsonAllCredentials));
    })
</script>

}
```

Just to clarify, on the initial load of the page, the "UnselectedCredentials" list is appearing properly (meaning that all credentials from the AllCredentials array with "IsSelected" value equal to false (which is everything at first) are appearing). The issues I'm having are related to the view (and potentially viewmodel) not updating correctly after the double click trigger to toggle the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be the initial load of the JSON data.  If I'm not mistaken, Knockout does NOT automatically make the properties of a JSON object observable.  An observableArray only sees when an item is added to or removed from the array, not whether an item within it is changed.  You might need to write a deserializer for the JSON data or make a Credential class with a constructor function (making all the properties observable) that you can feed the elements of the JSON data into before putting them in the observable array.

Look into the [Knockout Mapping Plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  That could help

I'm not sure if you are constrained by the viewmodel or not, but I would also suggest simplifying a bit.  There is really no reason to have multiple arrays and move items back and forth.  A simpler implementation would be to have a single array, displaying in tables according to whether the Selection property is true or false.  Like this:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldName_td">
                @Html.Label("Available Credentials")
            </td>
            <td class="fieldData_td">
                 <table data-bind="foreach:Credentials">
                     <!-- ko if: !Selected -->
                     <tr>
                         <td data-bind="text><select data-bind="text: Name, $root.click: toggleSelected></td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldName_td">
                @Html.Label("Selected Credentials")
            </td>
            <td class="fieldData_td">
                 <table data-bind="foreach:Credentials">
                     <!-- ko if: Selected -->
                     <tr>
                         <td data-bind="text><select data-bind="text: Name, $root.click: toggleSelected></td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
}
```

In your viewmodel, put all the credentials in one observable array (each property of the credential should be observable as well) and then the only work the viewmodel has to do (as long as the Selected property is observable) is

```
toggleSelection = function(credential) {
    credential.Selected = !credential.Selected;
}
```

Then, when you need to use the selected credentials, simply filter the array for those that are selected.

Good luck.

EDIT: Concerning the Credential class, assuming the only properties are Name and Selected, might look something like:

```
function Credential(name, selected) {
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
    this.Selected = ko.observable(selected);
}
```

And then you can cycle through your array of JSON data

```
 var Credentials = ko.observableArray();
 credentialsFromJson.forEach(function(c) {
     var credential = new Credential(c.Name, c.Selected);
     Credentials.push(credential);
 }
```

That makes each property observable.  If there are a lot of properties you want to watch, look at the ko.mapping plugin mentioned above.

Does this help?  If I'm reading the code correctly, the computed arrays aren't updating because there is nothing happening that KO is watching, and making the Selected property observable should fix that.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by making a credential class with a constructor function? Would that be in my viewmodel?

Comment: Yes.  I'm updating the answer to explain.

Comment: I hate to be a bother, but I can't seem to get the credentialsFromJson.forEach(function(c) {
     var credential = new Credential(c.Name, c.Selected);
     Credentials.push(credential);
 }  to work correctly. I've tried putting it in my Init function and placing it in a private function of its own, but there is a syntax error it seems, its expecting a ')'

Comment: @john, so sorry. After the last '}' there should be ');' to close the for each statement.  My bad.

Comment: Okay, I got it all working correctly. Thanks so much!